# How to properly include windows.h and set minimum version to XP

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll, include, windows-xp

I'm currently building a C++ DLL, and I have this at the top of the main DLL `.cpp` file. This currently is causing the warning `"Warning C4005: '_WIN32_WINNT' : macro redefinition"`. What have I done wrong?

I need to include `windows.h`, `SDKDDKVer.h` and set the minimum windows version to XP. How do I correct my code?

```
// System Includes
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d9.h>

// Windows Version
#define _WIN32_WINNT _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should include the SDK stuff first:

```
// Windows Version
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501     // _WIN32_WINNT_WINXP
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>

// System Includes
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
```