# Cannot include XACT3 header

Tags: audio, windows-8, directx, game-engine, xact

I am trying to include the xact3.h header file in a game project but i keep getting some errors related to mmreg.h

```
#include <xact3.h>
#include <Windows.h>

1>c:\program files\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\mmreg.h(2469): error C2332: 'struct' : missing tag name
1>c:\program files\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\mmreg.h(2469): warning C4094: untagged 'struct' declared no symbols
1>c:\program files\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\mmreg.h(2469): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__uuidof'
1>c:\program files\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\mmreg.h(2469): error C2059: syntax error : '__uuidof'
1>c:\program files\windows kits\8.0\include\shared\mmreg.h(2470): warning C4005: 'KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM' : macro redefinition
```

Those above are some of the errors i get. I am using Windows 8 if that is relevant. I've tried a lot of things like defining WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN or rearanging the headers but without success. Can someone tell me what could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601003/how-to-properly-include-windows-h-and-set-minimum-version-to-xp

Comment: are you saying that i should set the minimum windows version to XP? I tried it but i get the following error ': #error :  "This version of XAudio2 is available only in Windows 8 or later. Use the XAudio2 headers and libraries from the DirectX SDK with applications that target Windows 7 and earlier versions." c:\program files\windows kits\8.0\include\um\xaudio2.h'

Comment: so set minimum windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it by adding the XAudio2 header above the xact3 header